# What's the difference between "fluctuate" and "teeter"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, differences

What's the difference between "fluctuate" and "teeter"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fluctuate = vary with time. Think graph, chart.

Teeter:
(1) go back and forth (between the same two things/values). Think teeter-totter.
(2) be on the verge of something - the current little wiggles/variations are likely to soon change into a huge plummet. Think cartoon character balanced on the edge of the cliff.

Comment: Also, "fluctuate" is more formal than "teeter". And to my British ears, "teeter" seems more American. Apart from the phrase "teetering on the brink", I would normally say "wobble" rather than "teeter".

Comment: Maybe. But I just wouldn't say "teeter".